# Complexity of recurrence

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given ,

L(n) = 0 where n = 1,
   L(n) = L(n/2) where n > 1
a) Find L(25).
b) What will be the complexity of L.

Please answer these above two questions and do illustrate your answers

Comment: What do you mean by "the complexity of L"? Do you mean "what is the complexity of L as a function?" Or do you mean "what is the time (or space) complexity of L if it were implemented in code (for example: `def L(n): return 0 if n == 1 else L(n//2)`). Are we to assume `/` is truncating division?

Comment: L (n)=0 for all n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be `O(logn)`

As it n gets divided by 2 . It runs approximately `logn` steps before stopping.

```
n->n/2->n/4->n/8..n/2^k...1

so k=log(n)

It will be O(k)~O(logn).
```

It is not defined for odd number.

But if we consider floor to a number then it will be like

```
L(25)=L(12)=L(6)=L(3)=L(1)=0...
```

I would recommend you to know the question first.

Comment: what about the L(25) ?

Comment: Only this much information was provided in the question , anyway got the point.. thnx :)